# IntelliJ idea doesn't show the line which throws an exception

Tags: exception, intellij-idea

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.package.name.classname.methodname(+n1)
    at blablabla (+n2)
```

When the application throws an exception IntelliJ Idea show the following lines. How can I find which line has thrown this exception? I thought that n1 is the line's number but it's not - it's an empty line. So how can I find that line and what's n1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class which has been loaded is not the same as you are looking the source code. E.g. different versions of binary and sources.

Sometimes the same class appears several times under classpath.

Sometimes a debugger could show wrong line if file has mix of cr/lf (however never seen it with the IDEA).

Sometimes a build-time or run-time instrumentation could confuse a debugger.

Comment: so how can I find the line which really threw an exception?

Comment: 1) Find exactly the same version of source code and find the line of code. 2) Read the code of methodname and try to guess ;) 3) Use JAD to decompile the .class, it has option `output original line numbers as comments`.

Answer (score 0):

Was the application compiled with the debug info enabled? Was it obfuscated?